# Does Docker replicate read only directories on each container?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

Let us say, I have a docker image, with one quite large read only directory. Now, If I run say 10 containers on the same node, would each docker container contain a copy of that read only directory, or would they somehow be sharing that directory on the node where they are running on.

If they do somehow share read only directories, to save space, would we have to make such a directory read only explicity, or would docker containers use some sort of copy-on-write mechanism, where if you don't modify files of a directory, the docker containers would just be sharing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They share the underlying directory in the image.  The kernel provides a copy-on-write facility.  The [Storage overview](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) in the Docker documentation explains a little bit more about this, but there's not a lot you need to know unless you're actively developing Docker itself: if you `docker run` multiple containers from the same image then they share the base OS and application files stored in the image.

Comment: What I understand from what you are saying, is that as long as no docker container modifies a directory, they would be sharing it, but as soon as one docker container modifies a directory, it would first be given a copy of that directory, and its version of directory would therefore become different than those of the other containers who didn't modify that directory?